# Using callbacks to run function using the current values in a class

Tags: python, maya

I struggled to think of a good title so I'll just explain it here. I'm using Python in Maya, which has some event callback options, so you can do something like `on save: run function`. I have a user interface class, which I'd like it to update when certain events are triggered, which I can do, but I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing it.

Here is a basic example similar to what I have:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x
    def run_this(self):
        print self.x
    def display(self):
        print 'load user interface'

#Here's the main stuff that used to be just 'test().display()'
try:
    callbacks = [callback1, callback2, ...]
except NameError:
    pass
else:
    for i in callbacks:
        try:
            OpenMaya.MEventMessage.removeCallback(i)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

ui = test(5)
callback1 = OpenMaya.MEventMessage.addEventCallback('SomeEvent', ui.run_this)
callback2 = OpenMaya.MEventMessage.addEventCallback('SomeOtherEvent', ui.run_this)
callback3 = ......
ui.display()
```

The callback persists until Maya is restarted, but you can remove it using `removeCallback` if you pass it the value that is returned from `addEventCallback`. The way I have currently is just check if the variable is set before you set it, which is a lot more messy than the previous one line of `test().display()`

Would there be a way that I can neatly do it in the function? Something where it'd delete the old one if I ran the `test` class again or something similar?

Comment: So you would _never_ want multiple callbacks registered to run the same function (at the same time)?

Comment: Nope, I'd like to have different callbacks for different events, but just one thing per event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you might want to try this.

You can an have a persistent object which represents your callback manager, and allow it to hook and unhook itself.

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import maya.cmds as cmds
om.MEventMessage.getEventNames()

class CallbackHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, cb, fn):
        self.callback = cb
        self.function  = fn
        self.id = None

    def install(self):
        if self.id:
            print "callback is currently installed"
            return False
        self.id = om.MEventMessage.addEventCallback(self.callback, self.function)
        return True

    def uninstall(self):
        if self.id:
            om.MEventMessage.removeCallback(self.id)
            self.id = None
            return True
        else:
            print "callback not currently installed"
            return False

    def __del__(self):
        self.uninstall()

def test_fn(arg):
    print "callback fired 2", arg

cb = CallbackHandler('NameChanged', test_fn)
cb.install()
# callback is active
cb.uninstall()
# callback not active
cb.install()
# callback on again
del(cb) # or cb = None
# callback gone again
```

In this version you'd store the CallbackHandlers you create for as long as you want the callback to persist and then manually uninstall them or let them fall out of scope when you don't need them any more.

Another option would be to create your own object to represent the callbacks and then add or remove any functions you want it to trigger in your own code. This keeps the management entirely on your side instead of relying on the api, which could be good or bad depending on your needs.  You'd have an `Event()` class which was callable (using `__call__()`  and it would have a list of functions to fire then its' `__call__()` was invoked by Maya.  There's an example of the kind of event handler object you'd want [here](https://github.com/theodox/mGui/blob/master/mGui/events.py)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's a really good idea and seems to work great, but just another quick question, is there any alternative to `__del__` that will trigger even if `cb` is assigned to a different variable (to be on the safe side)? Part of the user interface deletes the window if it already exists, so that might be the perfect place to add the code if I set it as a global variable. The second option though sounds a bit too tricky, my OpenMaya knowledge is very basic, so I don't know how I'd even go about accessing the events without it haha.

Comment: I also just noticed you used a slightly different import, is `maya.OpenMaya` pretty much the same as `maya.api.OpenMaya`?

Comment: `maya.api` imports the 'new' api, also known as "api2".  It's faster and easier to work with, but less complete than the old one. It's the one you're supposed to use unless you need one of the functions that have not been migrated yet

Comment: __del__ gets called when an object falls out of scope.  Unfortunately it's hard to know when that will happen, it's easy in my test case but in a more complex system you might not remember to clear it out.  

You can also make a scriptJob that fires when a given piece of UI is deleted that unhooks any callbacks

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, `scriptJob` works perfectly in this case. One final question as it doesn't seem to cover it in the documentation, do you know if it would be possible to pass in arguments with the functions? It's not needed currently, but may end up useful in the future.

Comment: To bundle arguments with a callback script, try a `functools.partial` or a callable object.  It'll work like the button scripts described [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html)

Comment: Thanks, the lambda way seems to do the trick, shame it's not a functionality built in like with OpenMaya :P

Comment: @theodox  are you sure with the import maya.api.OpenMayal as om; om.MEventMessage.getEventNames?, because i cant get the module,eg: "print dir(om)", and i cant find it under: http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/python-api/